# Parallel php processes

Tags: php, parallel-processing

To increase throughput i run another php process, but this method load server so much, exists any method for solving this problem?

```
while (true)
{
    $allSms = $mca->getSms(null, null, $params);
    
    if (!$allSms)
    {
        sleep($sleepTime);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($allSms as $sms)
        {
            $cmdNewProcess = "/usr/bin/php " . __DIR__  . "/process_sender.php " . $sms['id'] . " " . $sms['calledNumber'];
            exec($cmdNewProcess . " > /dev/null &");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, `$allSms` always has a value, and that is why it is always getting to the else block. you need to figure out if that is the correct behaviour you want, if not why does `$allSms` always have a value.

Comment: You are not pausing between your execs.  Sounds like you need to sleep bettween sends or manage your workers better.

Comment: $allSms -  Total records for sending sms, if in DB no values i make sleep for 3 seconds for no overloading database

Comment: @quaresma89 you sleep when there are no database results, otherwise it will fire up processes for every message by the looks of your code.  You probably need to batch them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you don't want to spawn unlimited processes to process your tasks, but a limited number of "workers".

One approach is to use a message queue for this.

Consider this: PHP Code -> Message Queue -> Worker

There are multiple queue implementations available, you can for example use the enqueue package https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev
which supports multiple different message queues in the background.
Some frameworks (like Laravel) also provide message queue functionality out-of-the-box.

So your PHP process sends all messages you want to send (in that case the content of `$allSms`) to the queue. You start let's say 8 workers in the background which are running in an endless loop and fetch messages from the queue. They will pick up the messages and process them (probably sending them out, if it's SMS).

This way you can define how many processes will run at the same time, by choosing how many workers to start.
The tricky part here is choosing the right message queue and that the workers need to be monitored and restarted if they crash. If you don't use something like Kubernetes, you can use services like system.d, upstart or s6 to manage them.

Comment: Interesting idea, i will prepare functionality and will test this method. Thank's